# IOS img are not displaying

Tags: ios, image, retina.js

For some reason some images in img tag are not displaying on first visit on iPhone/iPad. And they are not displaying randomly. So if you clean caches and refresh page some images will be replaced with question mark. I use retinaJS on site. Can enybody explain why this happens? Is there some limit for ios image downloading?
Test site url http://test.ffwdlabs.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All images loaded fine on my iPhone 5 (on a 50 MB wifi connection) it just took forever (ok, more than 30 seconds)

You should optimise for mobile performance by first loading smaller images. It looks like the full size image you're showing on the desktop is being downloaded to the iPhone too and most of it is not even visible.

First image: 
I see a pixelated hand on the iPhone. Rest of image not visible...should it be scaled?

Use web kit inspector to check the load times of your images.

Safari and images:
https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/SafariImageDeliveryBestPractices/ServingImagestoRetinaDisplays/ServingImagestoRetinaDisplays.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012449-CH3-SW1

Allows you to inspect mobile safari (simulator and device)
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html

http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-using-web-inspector-to-debug-mobile-safari--webdesign-8787

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It not solves my problem but this resources are very helpful. One more problem is that I don't have own device or Mac to do tests or optimization :)